# Could Not find the Main class.Program Will exit

Tags: m2eclipse

this is NaveenKumar from Banglore here my problem is i tried to run the java programs in Eclipse Id in my machine but when i was tried to run my java program in Eclipse Id, then it is displaying a Error Dialog Box jest like as "Could Not find the Main class.Program will exit, like wise it is displaying. For this what to do please provide me the your valauble answers to my mail....

Answer (score 0):

You have a class which has a public main() method?

Select the class in the Package Explorer, rightClick -> Run As Java Application

That should be all you need.